# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in CODE

Tags: php

I have a php script that gives me one error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in CODE on line 58
```

I dont know much things about php and i hope somebody will take a look in the code and tell me whats wrong, please.

If i delete the ; on link 58 it keeps continue on every ";"

Here is the code:

```
http://pastebin.com/86zLG73M
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've answered as a freebie because you are new here. However, in future, please debug your code _first_ and narrow your problems down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't write `( integer )`; put there a value in...?

Answer (score 6):

Line 58 is:

```
$_SESSION['group_id'] = ( integer );
```

But this makes no sense. `( integer )` is not a valid PHP expression.

I'd correct it for you, but I have no idea what you intended by it. Neither does the PHP interpreter, which is why it gets to the semi-colon and goes mad... no wonder the `;` is "unexpected"!